# Advice on accessing Logitech BRIO features

Tags: authentication, hardware, webcam, biometrics, infrared

For my university project I must develop a windows app which recognises a user based on two biometrics - fingerprint and facial heat signature. This is very new and exciting territory for me as I will encounter difficult challenges that I have not yet faced and the learning curve will be very steep but fruitful.

My question relates to the camera which I will attempt to use for facial heat signature recognition. This is it: http://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/brio

It is relatively new and Logitech have not released any dev SDK for it and as such I am stuck on how to get under its hood/bonnet and integrate it with my app.  I am looking for advice on how I can go about doing it and assess whether it is feasible, in any case.  If it is not then I can not afford to waste my time on it and will have to come up with new ideas.

As an aside, it can be used for Windows Hello.

In short, I am looking for advice on how I can approach this challenge or whether I should at all. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to access through [`MediaCapture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture) and [`MediaFrameSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.frames.mediaframesource) classes. It works for me. But its only 340x340 30fps camera. And IR diode blinking about 15-20 Hertz so there is blinks in IR frame.
C# used.